# Access fitbit live heartbeat data from 3rd party iOS/Android app

Tags: android, ios, fitbit

Is there any possibility to access live heartbeat data on a fitbit wearable from my own iOS or Android app?

I know that there is a Web API to access data that has already been synced to the cloud, but I am interested in "realtime" data.

Comment: I think realtime data syncing is not possible into your own iOS/android app. I have upgraded the existing sample project to nougat and trying to achieve realtime sync. You may contribute on this project https://github.com/Asad-noor/FitbitTestApi

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Fitbit API as long as you have network access. You can get realtime data through subscriptions. You cannot interact over bluetooth